# Pandas Dataframe Filtering Columns and return column name

Tags: python, pandas, filter

How can i filter a Pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
Head   Cat1   Cat2   Cat3
"A"     0      0      1
"B"     1      0      1
```

So that it returns for every row the Category-Column-Names if not 0

For example

```
"A"   "Cat3"
"B"   "Cat1" "Cat3"
```

I have no idea how to solve this and i deeply appreciate every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the columns first to get the cols of interest and then call `apply` and use the boolean mask to mask the cols:

```
In [18]:
cat_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Cat')]
df[cat_cols].apply(lambda row: ', '.join(cat_cols[row == 1]), axis=1)

Out[18]:
0          Cat3
1    Cat1, Cat3
dtype: object
```

Also possible to retrieve the columns by accessing the `.index` attribute:

```
df[cat_cols].apply(lambda row: ', '.join(row.index[row == 1]), axis=1)
```